# Python: create all derivatives of string by replacing its symbols

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

I've got some dict like that

```
d = {'a' : ['1', '+', '='], 'b' : ['2'], c : ['3']}
```

My goal is to create a list of all possible derivatives from initial word by replacing its elements like that:

```
word = 'abcde'
rez = ['abcde', 
       '1bcde', '+bcde', '=bcde', 
       'a2cde', '12cde', '+2cde', '=2cde', 
       'ab3de', '1b3de', '+b3de', '=b3de', 'a23de', '123de', '+23de', '=23de']
```

Order of words in `rez` is not important.

I feel that there should be some easy way with `itertools`, but I can't see it. 
Any nice and beautiful solution would be very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is always the answer for these kind of problems. There may be better alternatives but the first that comes to my mind is using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

[''.join(chars) for chars in product(*[[x] + d.get(x, []) for x in word])]
```

*Output*

```
['abcde', 'ab3de', 'a2cde', 'a23de', '1bcde', '1b3de', '12cde', '123de',
 '+bcde', '+b3de', '+2cde', '+23de', '=bcde', '=b3de', '=2cde', '=23de']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you, guys! Every solution received +1 from me, but this one is also the fastest (and simplest, to my mind).

Answer (score 4):

Here is one approach.  Since you want to allow non-replacement (e.g., leaving "a" as "a"), it is better to include the original character in the list of replacement values, so that the dict has, e.g., `'a': ['a', '1', '+', '=']`.  This can be done with:

```
for k in d:
    d[k].append(k)
```

Then:

```
subs = [[(k, v) for v in vs] for k, vs in d.iteritems()]  
rez = []
for comb in itertools.product(*subs):
    baseword = word
    for before, after in comb:
        baseword = baseword.replace(before, after)
    rez.append(baseword)
```

The result:

```
['123de', '1b3de', '12cde', '1bcde', '+23de', '+b3de', '+2cde', '+bcde', '=23de', '=b3de', '=2cde', '=bcde', 'a23de', 'ab3de', 'a2cde', 'abcde']
```

Comment: doesn't give the result as specified by OP.

Comment: @isedev: Yes it does.  They're in a different order, but he says that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. No `import`, no `def`, no indentation.

```
d = {'a' : ['1', '+', '='], 'b' : ['2'], 'c' : ['3']}
for key in d: d[key].append(key)
print reduce(lambda items, f: sum(map(f, items), []), [lambda msg, c=c: [msg.replace(c, r) for r in d[c]] for c in d.keys()], ["abcde"])
```

Result:

```
[
    '123de', '1b3de', '12cde', '1bcde', 
    '+23de', '+b3de', '+2cde', '+bcde', 
    '=23de', '=b3de', '=2cde', '=bcde', 
    'a23de', 'ab3de', 'a2cde', 'abcde'
]
```